# How to prevent Microsoft Teams from launching at startup in Debian

Tags: linux, debian, microsoft-teams

I installed Microsoft Teams in Linux (Debian Stable-11) by downloading the deb file from [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/microsoft-teams/download-app#desktopAppDownloadregion) and installing it. Now I find that it launches every time I start Linux. I cannot find any menu item to prevent it from launching at startup.

How can I prevent Teams to launch at startup? Thanks for your help.

Edit:
On pressing `...`, I get only "Troubleshooting details", not any Settings:

[image]

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/374012/how-to-manage-startup-applications-in-debian-9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At least on this version:

```
$ dpkg -l teams
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name           Version      Architecture Description
+++-==============-============-============-==================================>
ii  teams          1.4.00.26453 amd64        Microsoft Teams for Linux is your >
```

this is available only *after* having signed in. It's accessible through Teams' settings in the top right corner of the main window.

`...` -> `Settings`:

[image: settings]

In the `General` menu, below `Application` uncheck the square named `Auto-start application`:

[image: auto-start application]

Without this it will always reinstall an auto-start entry for the Desktop (typically as `~/.config/autostart/teams.desktop`), which even if deleted by an other mean, will be recreated the next time the application is started.

Comment: On pressing `...`, I only get "Troubleshooting details", not any Settings.

Comment: I have added screenshot in my question above.

Comment: Yes, I could change the settings and it is not launching at startup now. Thanks.

Comment: ms providing yet another reliable pain in the rear